# c#, reflection.emit trying hard

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection, invoke, emit

I wanted to try how the `System.Reflection.Emit` works, but eventually I've stack with some problem. I wanted to create (using `Emit`) some simple class, like this:

```
using System;

namespace emit
{
    class Builder
    {
        private String name;

        public Builder(String builderName)
        {
            name = builderName;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return name.GetHashCode();
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.name;
        }
    }
}
```

I've been through some tutorials and I've managed to create dynamic library. I've saved that library on my disk and then loaded it using reflection. I was able to filter it's types, constructors and methods. I also succesfully invoked the constructor passing desired `string`. Yet, there's a problem when I'm trying to invoke any of methods- `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException` is thrown.

Here's how I implemented `GetHashCode()`:

```
MethodBuilder mHashCode = tBuilder.DefineMethod("GetHashCode",
                MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.Virtual,
                CallingConventions.HasThis, typeof(System.Int32), null);
            mHashCode.SetImplementationFlags(MethodImplAttributes.Managed);
            ILGenerator mHashGenerator = mHashCode.GetILGenerator();

            MethodInfo defaultHashCode = typeof(object).GetMethod("GetHashCode");

            mHashGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, simpleName);
            mHashGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, defaultHashCode);
            mHashGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

`tBuilder` is `TypeBuilder` that I'm creating.

After saving the assembly and looking into with `ILDSASM` it's like:
[image]

And the `EditModule.dll`:
[image]

Unfortunately, this method won't invoke. Here's the code:

```
                Type dType = asm.GetTypes()[0];
                ConstructorInfo dConstructor = dType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(string) });
                object dObject = dConstructor.Invoke(new object[] { "Pawel" });
                MethodInfo[] dMethods = dType.GetMethods();
                foreach(var mi in dMethods)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(mi.Name);
                }
                //method with `0` index is `GetHashCode()`
                dMethods[0].Invoke(dObject, null);
```

Does anyone have an idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: What's the inner exception of the TargetInvocationException ?

Comment: It's something like `CLR Environment has captured inappropriate program`. StackTrace shows that `BuilderEmitType.GetHashCode()` causes that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fragment

```
mHashGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, simpleName);
```

is trying to get the field value, but you forgot that in order to do that it needs an **instance**. Since the method you are building is an instance method, **this** is the hidden first argument of the method, so to get the value of `this.name` you should use the following

```
mHashGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
mHashGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, simpleName);
```

Comment: That's right! Thanks, I've misunderstood meaning of `CallingConvention`  enumeration.